# Sending mdm payload

Tags: iphone, plist, mdm, payload, apns-php

I am developing an MDM solution.

I have installed a configuration profile on device.
So I have all the required things like
Device Token, Push Magic String, UDID of device, etc.

Now I want to send a mdm payload to the device using APNS.
I am able to send a simple alert message to the device, but I need to send a mdm payload.

I am not sure how to send a plist(XML) to the device using APNS.

I am using php to send Push notifications.

Please if someone could help me how to send a mdm payload to the device.

Thanks,
Manmay

Comment: I was able to send a pushmagic payload using php-apns and the device sends a idle status as response to my server. Now I need to send a DeviceLock command.. But I am not able to send it.. :(

Comment: When I send a DeviceLock payload just like how I sent the PushMagic, the response is coming blank also the command is not executed on the device.. :(

Comment: Hi Manmay . How are you sending pushmagic payload using php-apns ?

Answer (score 1):

The MDM payloads are not public available. To use mdm you must register at apple (ios-mdm@apple.com).

Comment: If you have an enterprise dev account, the PDF is downloadable from the iOS Provisioning portal - Certificates / Other.

Comment: I am using Push Notification service of my developer program. Do I need an Enterprise Program to deal with mdm payload delivery to devices?

Also I have some PDF like mobiledevicemanagementprotocol.pdf iPhoneOTAConfiguration.pdf from Apple, do I get something different in Enterprise Program Provisioning Portal?

Comment: I was able to send the first payload with mdm:PushMagic, the device returned the status as idle to the MDM Server.. Now I need to send a simple devicelock command to the device. I am sending the devicelock plist to the device the same way as I send the mdm:PushMagic, but the response received is blank... PLEASE HELP

Comment: Hi Manmay .. How did you send the mdm:PushMagic ?

Answer (score 1):

install iphone config utility ..
    create a new Configuration profile...
    while creating go to mobile device management tab..
    we can find  **server url** and **check in url.**..
    we need not know that mdm payload cannot be send through apple push notification service..
    only we can send {mdm:"push magic token"}..
    first try to install mdm payload manually..
    after installation the device with payload will **Initially** (first time)  will respond to check in url sending push magic token.. device token.. and udid..
   then using push magic token we can send the push notification.

**then the device will poll commands through server url..**
   we can send commands like examples lock .. unlock..  in response (mime type : plist)and we can terminate connection by sending 200

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can't send the payload directly to the device. Here's how the delivery work :

1. MDM Server triggered APNS
2. Device receive the APNS and send idle response
3. MDM Server response the device query with Payload
4. Device send ACK to server

So the APNS work just for triggering the device to connect to server and then query what command available for that device.

Comment: Hi leo.. I am sending command to device but nothing happens on device. I am not able to figure out whether server trggered APNs succesfully. I am also not receiving idle response from device.  Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

prepare xml in a txt file and response it as a flow, it's ok